# PostgreSQL password error in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am new to PHP and have a simple problem but I have not been able to solve it. I have a database on a private server and use the following code for the login:

```
$conn_string=("host=###### port=###### dbname=test user=###### password=$######")
```

My problem is that I get an error because my password starts with a $ and it is being regarded as a variable. So I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ######## in C:\wamp\www\test\register.php on line 20
```

I thought because the the password was within the quotes that it would be exempt from this, so I was wondering if there was a quick fix or if I will have to change the password I use to login to the private server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches. Put the string in single quotes, which don't interpret variables:

```
$conn_string=('host=####### port=###### dbname=test user=###### password=$#######')
```

or escape the `$` character:

```
$conn_string=("host=####### port=###### dbname=test user=###### password=\$#######")`
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your password starts with a `$` and is inside of double quotes string.

Solutions:

```
$conn_string = 'host=####### port=###### dbname=test user=###### password=$#######' 
or
$conn_string = "host=####### port=###### dbname=test user=###### password=/$#######"
```

Comment: @gestalt also, you don't need the brackets.

Comment: Yeh I just added them to see if that would solve the problem, I didn't know the difference between the single and double quotes. Thanks again :)